# encode mp3 dynamically with CBR 128 to play with red5

Tags: mp3, red5

I am using ffmpeg to convert mp3 file with constant bit rate 128 and I need to play these mp3 files with red5 server. Some mp3 files have distortion issue streaming with red5. Please let me know what encoding method I should use to play mp3 with red5 in best quality.

Thanks